# Different Datatypes in multiple databases using Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, types, multiple-databases

I have an application which uses multiple database (Oracle, SQL Server , Informix) and need to mapping a class to different datatypes. For example:

```
COLUMN: DOCUMENTDATA

ORACLE    DATATYPE: BLOB
SQLSERVER DATATYPE: VARBINARY(MAX)
INFORMIX  DATATYPE: TEXT
```

How I do it in my `classmap`?

Comment: Do you want to use the schema generation tool of NHibernate? If not, just ignore the datatype of the column (don't specify it in the mapping), NHibernate doesn't need (or use) it at runtime.

Comment: I need only interact with the table. No need to create it. So in this way do not need to specify the type of the column, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to put it in your mapping, just leave it.